# Read contents of folder with Ajax WITOUT jquery

Tags: ajax

Setup:

html file on local machine in parent dir

js file in sub dir

image files in sub dir "Fotos"

Following code in js file:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (true/*this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200*/) {
        alert(this.responseText);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "/Fotos", true);
xhttp.send();
```

This causes TWO alerts to pop up with completely empty message box. I tried playing around with the directory path, but nothing changed, even with just "/". If I delete the true and replace it with the line in /* it doesn't yield a message box at all.

I was hoping to get some form of parsable list of image files from this.

I realize this has been solved with jQuery before, but I want to do this without, as it *should* be simple enough. Well, *why isn't* it?

Comment: If it was simple jQuery would not exist. Also you'd need a lot more than a JavaScript library to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Do you actually have a /Fotos folder? Because I reproduce your error exactly if there is no such folder. And when retrieving an existing one, it actually returns text when state is 4 (success). (See my answer below)

Comment: Could your Fotos folder be inside another folder which is not the root one of the web server? If so, the initial '/' of your path should be removed (see answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails if the /Fotos folder does not exist (or does not have the correct permissions).

Additionally, for XMLHttpRequest to work, it needs the web page to be served by a web server. It must be accessed with http or https protocol (even if in localhost). E.g. http ://localhost/myfolder/pagewithcode.html Then, the Fotos folder must be a subfolder of "myfolder". The code would also work if the route is http: //localhost/pagewithcode.html (and Fotos is a subfolder of the one where pagewithcode.html is).

The code below (slightly modified from yours) gets the contents of the current folder (in which the html page with the JavaScript code is stored).

Notice that the responseText is HTML, with all the tags, not just the list of files, so that it could be shown in the browser.

```
<html>
  <body>
  <script>
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // enter here only when success
        console.log(this.readyState);
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }
      else {
        // enter here for all state changes except success
        console.log(this.readyState);
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", ".", true);
    xhttp.send();
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If Fotos is a subfolder of the one the html page is in, then you'd better remove the initial '/' of the path (otherwise, you are getting a Fotos folder in the *root* folder of the server):

```
xhttp.open("GET", "Fotos", true);
```

Comment: Basicially, you replaced the "/" with a ".", right? I copied your code, but the console stays empty, except for line breaks of course. I'm on Windows 7, does that matter in any way?

Comment: I have replaced the path of the folder. You are working with a web server, right? And accessing your html with http protocol (not file), right?

Comment: Try first your path directly in the browser. If it works (it actually finds the folder), then you just need to use in your code the folder path *relative* to your web page.

Comment: That's not it. Neither just "Fotos" nor "." work. I even put exactly your code in an html file in the Fotos folder and it still resulted in empty output. I'm on a local machine and that's where it's required.

Comment: For XMLHttpRequest to work, you need your web page to be served by a web server. It must be accessed with http or https protocol (even if in localhost). E.g. http ://localhost/myfolder/pagewithcode.html Then, the Fotos folder must be a subfolder of "myfolder". The code would also work if the route is http: //localhost/pagewithcode.html (and Fotos is a subfolder of the one where pagewithcode.html is). Putting the web page inside Fotos will not work (sorry for the spaces in the urls but stackoverflow hides the http protocol of the links)

Comment: Oh, I was lead to believe this would work on a local machine without additional setup. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: You're welcome. I have added the server explanation to the answer for future reference.